# How to get Selected Currency in k2 Store - Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, cart, k2

I am creating a payment plugin for my k2 Store powered by joomla 3.8.2.

I want to get current or selected currency code `USD`.

basically I am looking some helper function which return selected Currency. something like this  `K2Store::currency`

I found this `K2StoreFactory::getCurrencyObject()` but its return all currency instead selected one.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself, hope its help someone

```
$currency = K2StoreFactory::getCurrencyObject();
$currency_code = $currency->getCode();
```